# Optimizing portfolio in R with already known expected returns

Tags: r, optimization, quantitative-finance, portfolio

I am trying to do portfolio optimization in R based on asset returns, covariances and variance I have calculated elewhere for all periods. I would then do backtesting using the calculated weights and actual past returns of the assets.

I'm ultimately attempting to try multiple optimization methids, but decided t ostart off simple, with Markowtiz Variance Optimization.

Optimization packages/functions I've been able to find so far are able to do exactly what I'm trying t achieve, but just using returns data. On the other hand, I'm trying to utilize expected returns I have calculated wth a separate model which give me the expected returns & variance for all the assets instead of simplu utilizing past performance.

Is there a simple optimization formula to achieve this? I am abe to pull off the simple optimization in Excel, but this is way too heavy to perform for a large number of periods. Should I just do the optimizatin semi-manually, by using the underlying optimization formulas and some sort of "solver" for R?

I have tried to see how the most common optimization functions in R work, but they all seem to only utilize past returns data directly.

Comment: If you are looking for data modeling recommendations, this is not the right site to ask. Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for functions that take as inputs expected means and covariance matrices, and return mean-variance efficient portfolios (i.e. weight vectors).  You might want to have a look at functions [`minvar`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/NMOF/html/minvar.html), [`mvPortfolio`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/NMOF/html/mvFrontier.html), or [`maxSharpe`](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/NMOF/html/maxSharpe.html) in package [`NMOF`](https://cran.r-project.org/package=NMOF), which compute minimum-variance, mean-variance efficient and maximum Sharpe-ratio portfolios. Examples are in a package vignette [Functions for portfolio selection](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NMOF/vignettes/portfolio.pdf) . (Disclosure: I am the package maintainer.)

Comment: Thank you! This seems very useful. Is there a way to also include transactio costs in the optimization process somehow?

Comment: Not with these functions I am afraid.  But you if you are interested in backtests, you could easily wrap these functions in a backtest routine and subtract transaction costs.  See https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/39759/backtest-with-rolling-volatility-in-r
for an example of doing a backtest, and, for the case of proportional transaction costs, see the parameter `tc` in 
`PMwR::btest` https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/PMwR/html/btest.html .